# REST webservice + HTML using jquery libs is not working when deployed on same web application

Tags: jquery, html, web-services

I am facing issue when deploying my web application which have both rich UI using jquery-ui and webservices.

I am using Eclipse, TomeePlus1.6, jquery, webservice

I am not able to load the mentioned .css & .js files in my html.

I am getting error in firebug -

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/CVR_WS_GitHub/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/CVR_WS_GitHub/Styles/jquery-ui.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/CVR_WS_GitHub/Styles/demos.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/CVR_WS_GitHub/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/CVR_WS_GitHub/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
        $(document).ready(function() {
```

If I remove the webservice file, from my project. I am easily able to invoke my html with all Rich UI look & feel.

I spent 2 days, but really not understanding, what is going wrong here.

please help me on this.

here is my code.

**CVR_GitHub.html**

> CVR HTML
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
>           $( "#accordion" )
>         .accordion({
>           header: "> div > h3",
>           collapsible: true,
>           heightStyle: "content"
>         })
>         .sortable({
>           axis: "y",
>           handle: "h3",
>           stop: function( event, ui ) {
>             // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
>             // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
>             ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
>           }
>       });
>                               });     </script>
>
>  </head>
>  <body>
> <form action="" method="post">
>       <div id="accordion">
>           <div class="group">
>        <h3>Company Profile</h3>
>           <div>
>               <table>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td><label>CVR Title</label></td>
>                       <td><input type="text" name="CVRTitle"></td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>
>                   </tr>
>               </table>
>           </div>
>     </div>        </div>
> </form>   </body> </html>
> ```

**web.xml**

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
>   version="3.0">   CVR_WS_GitHub
>   
>       index.html
>       index.htm
>       index.jsp
>       default.html
>       default.htm
>       default.jsp
>
> ```
>  <servlet>    <servlet-name>myHTML</servlet-name>     <jsp-file>/CVR_Sample.html</jsp-file>   </servlet>
>   <servlet-mapping>   <servlet-name>myHTML</servlet-name>     <url-pattern>/samplehtml</url-pattern>   </servlet-mapping>
>  <servlet>    <servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>  <jsp-file>/CVR_Sample.jsp</jsp-file>   </servlet>
>   <servlet-mapping>   <servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>  <url-pattern>/samplejsp</url-pattern>   </servlet-mapping>
>
>  <servlet>    <servlet-name>myCVR</servlet-name>  <jsp-file>/CVR_GitHub.html</jsp-file>   </servlet>
>   <servlet-mapping>   <servlet-name>myCVR</servlet-name>  <url-pattern>/cvr</url-pattern>   </servlet-mapping>
> ```

Webservices
HelloWsService.java

> package com.ws.cvr;
>
> import javax.ws.rs.GET; import javax.ws.rs.Path; import
>   javax.ws.rs.PathParam; import javax.ws.rs.Produces; import
>   javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
>
> @Path("/cvrrest") public class HelloWsService {
>
> // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request   @GET
>     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)     public String sayDefault() {
>         return "Hello sayDefault";  }
>         // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request   @GET    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)     @Path("/text")  public String
>   sayPlainTextHello() {         return "Hello sayPlainTextHello";   }
>
> // This method is called if XML is request  @GET
>     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)   @Path("/xml")   public String
>   sayXMLHello() {       return "" + " Hello
>   sayXMLHello" + "";    }
>
> // This method is called if HTML is request     @GET
>     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)  @Path("/html")  public String
>   sayHtmlHello() {      return " " + "" + "Hello " +
>   ""
>                 + "
>
> ## " + "Hello sayHtmlHello" + "
>
> " + " ";    }
>
> ```
>   @GET    @Path("/hello/{param1}/{param2}")   public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param1") String msg1,@PathParam("param2") String
> ```
>
> msg2) {
>             String output = msg2+" Jersey say : getMsg := " + msg1;
>             return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();         }
>
> }

Thanks